# How to verify C functions with array parameters using Isabelle

Tags: c, isabelle, formal-verification, sta, sel4

I am using Isabelle to verify a C program. During the verification process, I used the c-parser install-C-file to load the code, but the following issue occurred：

```
attempt to cause decay to pointer on array without an address
```

The c code is as follows

```
void GetName(char result[32])
{
    static const char cv[11] = {'m','a','i','n','_','t','h','r','e','a','d'};
    long b_i;
    long i;
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        result[i] = '\0';
    }
    i = 1;
    for (b_i = 0; b_i < 11; b_i++) {
        i = b_i + 1;
        result[b_i] = cv[b_i];
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
}

typedef struct Attribute {
    char name[32];
} Attribute;

void PartitionInit() {
    Attribute a;    
    GetName(a.name);
}
```

The line of code that caused the error is `GetName(a.name);`

How can I make install-C-file load this file properly?

The error message in Isabelle is as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgqea.png).

```
1704726218: Added external decl for SetDiff with 3 args.
1704726218: Added external decl for GLOBAL Init with 0 args.
1704726218: Added external decl for GetProcessIndex with 2 args.
1704726218: Added external decl for SYS CREATE PROCESS with 4 args.
1704726218: Translating function Partition Init
/home/xxx/formal-c/Partition Init.c:43.10-43.24: Attempting to cause decay to pointer on array without an address
```

Comment: Do you have a definition of `GetName` ? That is the implementation of it. I would think that the error should say "without size" rather than "without address". Is it copied verbatim?

Comment: Note well that no C function accepts an array as a parameter.  Function declarations that seem to declare parameters having array type in fact declare those parameters as pointers, instead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have added more information. The error message is consistent with my description, and the function implementation has been added.

Comment: I am indeed aware of this, but now I need to pass an array to this function. How can I write the code so that Isabelle can verify it? @JohnBollinger

Comment: Perhaps you are aware of it, but you do not seem to understand it.  You *can't* pass an array to a function.  The C language does not provide any way to express that.  Your code is no exception.  It passes a *pointer* to function `GetName()`.  Indeed, the issue Isabelle is complaining about seems not to be the function call itself, but rather the automatic array-to-pointer conversion involved in evaluating argument `a.name`.

Comment: And as such, I am inclined to think that the issue reflects a flaw in the validator -- either it has come to an incorrect conclusion (because `a.name` is a valid lvalue at that point, so the object it designates absolutely does have an address), or it has issued a misleading diagnostic.

Comment: Any way around, Isabelle/C seems to be more a research tool than a production tool.  You might find somebody around here who knows enough about it to explain in detail how to apply it successfully to your code, but you would be much more likely to find help in the research group from which Isabelle and Isabelle/C emerged.

Comment: According to this article, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.10630.pdf , it appears there is more than one analysis engine available with Isabelle. This link, https://afp.theoremproving.org/entries/isabelle_c/ , has a ton of material about Isabelle. Start with the README link at the bottom which goes to https://afp.theoremproving.org/entries/isabelle_c/theories/#README

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostic is indeed surprising: function `GetName` is defined as taking a pointer to `char` as an argument and you are passing an array of `char` which decays to a pointer to its first element.  No problem at all.  The prototype `void GetName(char result[32])` is equivalent to `void GetName(char *result)` and the call `GetName(a.name)` is equivalent to `GetName(&a.name[0])`.

The diagnostic wording is incorrect too: passing `a.name` effectively causes decay to pointer of the array `a.name`, but this array does have an address as `a` has been defined as a local object with automatic storage.  The object `a` is instantiated by the compiler upon entering the function body and the address of `a.name` is the same as that of `a` itself. No bug there.

The *array* length `32` in the prototype is meaningless, it is ignored.
Specifying a length in the prototype is confusing and may indicate a misconception by the programmer.  C99 introduced a new syntax to specify a minimum length of the array pointed to by a pointer received as an argument, which might be what the programmer intended to convey.  The syntax is

```
void GetName(char result[static 32])
```

Isabelle might be complaining about this potential confusion, but the diagnostic is incomprehensible,

You can try these modifications to see where Isabelle's confusion comes from:

- try changing the prototype of `GetName` to

  ```
  void GetName(char result[])
  ```
- try changing the prototype of `GetName` to

  ```
  void GetName(char *result)
  ```
- try changing the prototype of `GetName` to

  ```
  void GetName(char result[static 32])
  ```

  which is not equivalent to the posted one but more consistent with the requirement that `result` point to an array of at least 32 bytes.
- try intializing the `Attribute` object in `PartitionInit`:

  ```
  Attribute a = { "" };
  ```